# How to set a unique field to the relationship using Django?

Tags: django

I am building a tiny website host service, where an user can create a website and insert pages in it.

So I created the following classes:

```
class Website(models.Model):
    account = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    custom_domain = models.CharField(max_length=130, blank=True, unique=True) #optional
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Page(models.Model):
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
```

I want to make the field 'slug' unique only to the relationship between Website and Page classes. This way two sites can have a page with the same slug. Like this:

```
 http://mysite.com/website_1/contact_page
 http://mysite.com/webiste_2/contact_page
```

But the field option 'unique' is intended for that.

Any tips or best practices in cases like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the unique requirement on the slug column and add a [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) to the `Page`'s Meta 
class.

```
class Page(models.Model):
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('website', 'slug')
```

Comment: No problem. FYI: Django also has a built-in slug model field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

Comment: Thank you again! it was timely.